# BizTalk FTP - File Rename

Tags: biztalk

I need to send files using the BizTalk 2006 (non wcf) FTP adapter. After successful transmission of each file it needs to be renamed from an "A" prefix to a "U" prefix. I don't want to issue a command using wildcards because I can't be sure of other files in the destination folder.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you are doing this to avoid having the file picked up by anothe rprocess while it's in transit on the wire. You have two opetions.  First, in the **After Put** property of the FTP Send Port, type in the rename commangd.  Option Two, use the **Temporary Folder** propery of the FTP Send Port.  This temp folde ron the FTP site is where the file will be deposited during transfer.  After it's all there, the file will be moved to the destination.  The temporary folder will also allow you to recover from transfer failures where a connection might be lost.